# pivot in sql server with a twist

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on call center data to provide agent performance metrics. One of the table captures agent status in the following manner. This table captures agent status throughout the day in total seconds for every statuskey

```
UserID    | StartTime           | EndTime             | StatusKey   | StateDuration |
amjackson | 2016-04-25 12:12:14 | 2016-04-25 12:12:19 | followup    |             5 |
amjackson | 2016-04-25 12:12:19 | 2016-04-25 12:13:23 | Break       |            64 |
amjackson | 2016-04-25 12:13:23 | 2016-04-25 12:13:42 | available   |            19 |
amjackson | 2016-04-25 12:13:42 | 2016-04-25 12:19:42 | Break       |           360 |
amjackson | 2016-04-25 12:19:42 | 2016-04-25 12:21:55 | available   |           133 |
```

My requirement is to pivot the data based on statuskey but want two colums for Break as Break1 and Break2

```
UserID    | Date       | Followup | Break1 | Available | Break2 | 
amjackson | 2016-04-25 | 5        |    64  |   152     |    360 |
```

Hope I'm clear.
Any inputs would be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired output? I'm not sure what you're asking for

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE or derived table to select "Break" as either "Break1" or "Break2" (with a CASE Statement), and then PIVOT a SELECT from that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this could be interpreted. I read this as you want the sum of each StatusKey other than break and each break on its own. For what it is worth I would recommend normalizing your StatusKey to another table, but that is a topic for another day perhaps.

The first challenge you have here is you need to post some data so others can actually work on your problem in a format that makes it easy. Here is an example of a better way to post your sample data.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#something') is not null
    drop table #something

create table #something
(
    UserID varchar(10)
    , StartTime datetime
    , EndTime datetime
    , StatusKey varchar(10)
    , StateDuration int
)

insert #something
select 'amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:14', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', 'followup', '5' union all
select 'amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', 'Break', '64' union all
select 'amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', 'available', '19' union all
select 'amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', 'Break', '360' union all
select 'amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', '2016-04-25 12:21:55', 'available', '133';
```

Now that it is super simple for somebody to help the likelihood of receiving assistance goes up exponentially.

Here is one way you could solve this problem. This of course is making a lot of assumptions about the actual data and the actual requirements. The technique here is known as a cross-tab, sometimes also referred to as conditional aggregation. You could also use PIVOT. I prefer cross tabs as the syntax is less obtuse to me and they have been proven to be slightly faster. This could probably be simplified a little bit this does return the desired output you stated.

```
with GroupedValues as
(
    select UserID
        , convert(date, StartTime) as Date
        , StatusKey
        , StateDuration
        , StartTime
    from #something
    where StatusKey = 'Break'

    union all

    select UserID
        , convert(date, max(StartTime)) as Date
        , StatusKey
        , SUM(StateDuration) as TotalDuration
        , Min(StartTime)
    from #something
    where StatusKey <> 'Break'
    group by UserID
        , StatusKey
)
, SortedValues as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by StartTime) as RowNum
    from GroupedValues
)

select UserID
    , Date
    , Max(case when RowNum = 1 then StateDuration end) as Followup
    , Max(case when RowNum = 2 then StateDuration end) as Break1
    , Max(case when RowNum = 3 then StateDuration end) as Available
    , Max(case when RowNum = 4 then StateDuration end) as Break2
from SortedValues
group by UserID
    , Date
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree, you should try and normalize that data. Anyway, here is a solution using pivot. You probably cannot know what rows those breaks are in, so first you separate the non-break rows and append an ID to the StatusKey-values of those.
You also need to cast the values as date for the grouping to work.
Now we'll pivot over those, adding the StateDuration values for each StatusKey.
I'll put your values in a table variable @callc first.

```
DECLARE @callc TABLE(UserID nvarchar(100), StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime
        , StatusKey nvarchar(100), StateDuration int);
INSERT INTO @callc(UserID, StartTime, EndTime, StatusKey, StateDuration)
    VALUES('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:14', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', 'followup', 5)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', 'Break', 64)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', 'available', 19)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', 'Break', 360)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', '2016-04-25 12:21:55', 'available', 133);

SELECT  UserID
        , StartTime AS [date]
        , [followup]
        , [Break1]
        , [available]
        , [Break2]
FROM    (   SELECT  c.UserID
                    , CAST(c.StartTime AS date) AS [StartTime]
                    , c.StatusKey
                    , c.StateDuration
            FROM    @callc c
            WHERE   c.StatusKey != 'Break'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  b.UserID
                    , CAST(b.StartTime AS date) AS [StartTime]
                    , b.StatusKey + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.StartTime ASC) AS char(2))
                    , b.StateDuration
            FROM    @callc b
            WHERE   b.StatusKey = 'Break'
        ) t
PIVOT(SUM(StateDuration) FOR StatusKey IN([followup], [Break1], [available], [Break2])) p;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I tried using my table instead of variable but its throwing me an error "Arithametic overflow error converting expression to datatype varchar"

Answer (score 0):

And solution with dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @query AS nvarchar(4000),
        @columns AS nvarchar(4000)

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    UserID nvarchar(50),
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime,
    StatusKey nvarchar(50),
    StateDuration int
)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:14', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', 'followup', 5),
('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', 'Break', 64),
('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', 'available', 19),
('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', 'Break', 360),
('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', '2016-04-25 12:21:55', 'available', 133)  


SELECT @columns = STUFF((
SELECT ',' +  QUOTENAME(StatusKey + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID,StatusKey ORDER BY StartTime ) as nvarchar(10)))
FROM #temp
ORDER BY StartTime ASC
FOR XML PATH ('')
),1,1,'')

SELECT @query =
'SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  UserID,
            CAST(StartTime as DATE) as [Date],
            StatusKey + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID,StatusKey ORDER BY StartTime) as nvarchar(10)) AS StatusKey,
            StateDuration
    FROM #temp
    ) as p
PIVOT
(
SUM(StateDuration) FOR StatusKey IN ('+@columns+')
) as pvt'

EXEC(@query)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Output:

```
UserID    Date       followup1   Break1      available1  Break2      available2
--------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
amjackson 2016-04-25 5           64          19          360         133

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to post a comment up there, so I'll just do another post. The error you're getting is because you have over 100 'Break' rows in that table. Here is a corrected version, which should give you correct results, the old one could not deal with multiple UserIDs either. ;-)

```
DECLARE @callc TABLE(UserID nvarchar(100), StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime
        , StatusKey nvarchar(100), StateDuration int);
INSERT INTO @callc(UserID, StartTime, EndTime, StatusKey, StateDuration)
    VALUES('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:14', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', 'followup', 5)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', 'Break', 64)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', 'available', 19)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', 'Break', 360)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', '2016-04-25 12:21:55', 'available', 133);

SELECT  UserID
        , StartTime AS [date]
        , ISNULL([followup], 0) AS [followup]
        , ISNULL([Break1], 0) AS [Break1]
        , ISNULL([available], 0) AS [available]
        , ISNULL([Break2], 0) AS [Break2]
FROM    (   SELECT  c.UserId
                , CAST(c.StartTime AS date) AS [StartTime]
                , c.StatusKey
                , c.StateDuration
            FROM    @callc c
            WHERE   c.StatusKey != 'Break'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  b.UserId
                , CAST(b.startTime AS date)
                , b.StatusKey + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY b.StartTime ASC) AS nvarchar(50))
                , b.StateDuration
            FROM    @callc b
            WHERE   b.StatusKey = 'Break'
        ) t
PIVOT(SUM(StateDuration) FOR StatusKey IN([followup], [Break1], [available], [Break2]))p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way of doing it without using `PIVOT`. This also allows you to easily accommodate more than 2 breaks, or other multiple rows with the same `StatusKey` for that matter. The `CTE` is simple and doesn't have to change if you add/change `StatusKeys`. You just change the `SELECT` to give different results. (Hopefully my example illustrates this.)

Thanks to previous posters for the populate test data code.

```
 -- POPULATE TEST DATA ---------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @callc TABLE(UserID nvarchar(100), StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime
        , StatusKey nvarchar(100), StateDuration int);

INSERT INTO @callc(UserID, StartTime, EndTime, StatusKey, StateDuration)
    VALUES('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:14', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', 'followup', 5)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:12:19', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', 'Break', 64)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:23', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', 'available', 19)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:13:42', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', 'Break', 360)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:19:42', '2016-04-25 12:21:55', 'available', 133)
    , ('amjackson', '2016-04-25 12:22:55', '2016-04-25 12:27:55', 'Break', 300)


;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  C.UserID AS [UserID],       
            C.StateDuration AS [StateDuration],                         
            CAST (C.StartTime AS DATE) AS [Date],               
            (CONCAT(C.StatusKey, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C.UserID, C.StatusKey ORDER BY C.StartTime) AS varchar(1)))) AS [StatusKey]
    FROM    @callc AS C
) 
SELECT CTE.UserID AS [UserID],
        CTE.Date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.StatusKey Like 'Followup%' THEN CTE.StateDuration ELSE 0 END)                     
            AS 'Followup',
        SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.StatusKey = 'Break1' THEN CTE.StateDuration ELSE 0 END)   
            AS 'Break1',
        SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.StatusKey LIKE 'Available%' THEN CTE.StateDuration ELSE 0 END) 
            AS 'Available',
        SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.StatusKey = 'Break2' THEN CTE.StateDuration ELSE 0 END)       
            AS 'Break2',

        -- Extra statuses you could easliy use
        SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.StatusKey = 'Available2' THEN CTE.StateDuration ELSE 0 END) 
            AS 'Available2',
        SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.StatusKey = 'Break3' THEN CTE.StateDuration ELSE 0 END)       
            AS 'Break3',            
        SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.StatusKey LIKE 'Break%' THEN CTE.StateDuration ELSE 0 END)        
            AS 'Total Breaks'                   
FROM CTE
GROUP BY 
        CTE.UserID,
        CTE.Date;
```

Results:

```
UserID    | Date       | Followup | Break1 | Available | Break2 | Available2 | Break3 | Total Breaks
amjackson | 2016-04-25 |        5 |     64 |       152 |    360 |        133 |    300 |          724
```